# What is Pan's Shadow?

Tags: once-upon-a-time

In-universe, everyone refers to the black smoke monster as "Pan's Shadow", saying that it does his bidding. We also see that it is possible for a magic user to remove their own shadow and have it do their bidding as

> Rumplestiltskin does this to hide his knife.

In [*Think Lovely Thoughts*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Think_Lovely_Thoughts), we learn that

> the Shadow was on the island before Peter Pan existed.

**What is Pan's Shadow, and why does it seem to obey him?**

Answer (score 6):

Though everyone calls it Pan's shadow, it's more correct to call it Neverland's Shadow (or just The Shadow), since as you point out, it existed before there even was a Peter Pan. It obeys it's own set of rules, e.g. it can be trapped, it has magic of its own, etc.

Once it got ahold of Malcom, and turned him into Pan, it became "his" shadow because it suited its own needs just as well as Pan's. I'm pretty sure that it *wanted* Pan to become permanently immortal, because it set up everything perfectly to put that idea into his head: it granted him his youth, then immediately turns around and shows him the hourglass. It then tells Pan that nothing can live forever. That's almost guaranteed to get Pan obsessing over how to do just that.

As far as I know, the origins of The Shadow are never explained. It's simply some kind of seemingly malevolent entity that likes to cause havoc by way of granting wishes to people who will misuse them. It's tied to Never Land in some deep, fundamental way. Malcom himself describes it as:

> It's a friend; a part of the island. And, after I do what it told me, it will become a part of me too.

We can probably assume that the Shadow is a manifestation of the island itself, and perhaps it's helping Pan because it wants someone that will be around forever, not just when they're dreaming?